# PHP mixed with ASP

Tags: php, asp.net

I have a problem, just redone a homepage that was in ASP (ASPX) to a PHP.
The problem is that i have some links out there that gos like this www.example.com/work.aspx?jid=23 .

I need to take controll over the links a redriect them to the main page.

How to do that? I have created a work.aspx file that i have written som text just for test. When i try to change the file content to do a "Response.Redirect" the file dosent seam to update.. Why?

Regards

Comment: Because you don't execute PHP on a .aspx-file. Check your Apache/IIS config.

Comment: You are really better off replacing these with server redirects. Keeping random aspx files around just to redirect isn't a very good long-term solution. And if the goal is to get away from asp entirely, using server redirection will make that far easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to do that with .htaccess, not .aspx.  Remove your .aspx file

Create a file called `.htaccess`

Put this in it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^work.aspx$ work.php%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC,R=301]
```

This should take `www.example.com/work.aspx?jid=23` and make it `www.example.com/work.php?jid=23`

It'll also throw a 301 header telling search engines that the URL has been permanently moved.